# How can i inform ASP.NET that the a new User is created successfully?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

In my webpage i use a combination of the `CreateUserWizard` and a custom validation module.

Fortunately OR unfortunately the `CreateUserWizard` control *sees* that the user is not created successfully and displays the following message (although the user is added successfully as record, in my MS-SQL database).

`Your account was not created. Please try again.`

How can i inform the ASP.NET that the user is created successfully, so instead of the the message mentioned above, the user will be forwarded to the `ContinueDestinationPageUrl` of the `CreateUserWizard` control?

Comment: Are you using a custom membership provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreatedUser` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.createduser.aspx).

Markup:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ID="wizardAddUser" OnCreatedUser="wizardAddUser_CreatedUser">
    ...
</asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void wizardAddUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateUserWizard wizardAddUser = (CreateUserWizard)sender;
    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/{0}?user={1}", "Default.aspx", wizardAddUser.UserName));
}
```